# get a view of all pages displayed

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

```
if($isadmin==false){
            $type = array('EwtWork.userid'=>$userid, $sql);
            $this->paginate = array(
                'conditions'=> $type,
                'order'=>array('EwtWork.starttime'=>'desc'),
                'fields'=>array('date(EwtWork.starttime) as wdate', 
                                'time(EwtWork.starttime) as starttime', 
                                'time(EwtWork.endtime) as endtime', 'EwtWork.lateres', 
                                'EwtWork.earlyres', 'EwtWork.comments', 'EwtWork.overtime')
            );  
            $flag = 0;
        }else {
            $type = array($sql);
            $this->paginate = array(
                'conditions'=> $type,
                'order'=>array('EwtWork.starttime'=>'desc'),
                'joins' => array('JOIN ewt_users AS EwtUser ON (EwtWork.userid = EwtUser.id)'),
                'fields'=>array('date(EwtWork.starttime) as wdate', 
                                'time(EwtWork.starttime) as starttime', 'EwtUser.fullname',
                                'time(EwtWork.endtime) as endtime', 'EwtWork.lateres', 
                                'EwtWork.earlyres', 'EwtWork.comments', 'EwtWork.overtime')
            );
            $flag = 1;  
        }           
        $this->set('from', $from);
        $this->set('to', $to);
        $this->set('flag', $flag);      
        $this->set('exportdata', $this->paginate('EwtWork'));
```

I would like to not set the pagination limit for the above paginator. How can I reset the page limit to NULL of it such that I can get a view of all pages in a single view?

Comment: Be more specific. http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal You want all records if the user is admin? The code above should do that if you simply do what I've answered you inside the case isadmin is true.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$this->Model->find('all', array(...))` instead of pagination if you want all record and not paginate them.

Comment: Thanks, it paginates based on IsAdmin or not, I don't know how to distinguish these two cases.

Comment: I still don't understand your problem with that? You should use admin routing by the way: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/950/Prefix-Routing